# Can couchdb stop responding to requests coming to local couch db while replicating to cloud couch?

Tags: couchdb

There are recent events I have observed that couchdb looks like stalling requests if the initial replication process is failing after a restart to couch db node. Can the replication and requests to local couch db have a dependency such that ? The setup looks like where there are several nodes and all except one has push and pull links created towards to a one node in the master slave fashion. Couchdb version: 1.6